# How to calculate the limit of this integral?

Tags: integration, limits, analysis

Suppose $R>0$,
$$D_R=\{(r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta):0\leq r\leq R,0\leq \theta\leq \frac{\pi}{R^2} \},$$
and
$$I_R=\int\int_{D_R}\frac{x^2\cos y}{x^2+y^2+1}dxdy.$$
Caculate  $\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}I_R$.

My idea is to expand $\cos y$, remain the first two terms, then I get $0$. Is this correct?  My intuition tells me it's related to $\pi$. Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: The answer is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The idea is that $x\approx r$ and $\cos y\approx 1$ in the region $D_R$.

Comment: Shouldn’t there be an extra $r$ in the numerator?@SangchulLee

Comment: *Hint.* Study the domain carefully (make a picture or imagine). Now what happens as $R\to \infty$? In particular what can you say about the limiting value of $\theta$? What does this tell you about the limiting behaviours of $x, y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to polar coordinates we have that

$$I_R=\iint_{D_R}\frac{x^2\cos y}{x^2+y^2+1}~\mathrm{d}x~\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^R\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{R^2}}\frac{r^3\cos^2\theta\cos(r\sin\theta)}{r^2+1}~\mathrm{d}\theta~\mathrm{d}r.$$

Make the substitution

$$\begin{cases}
\varphi=R^2\theta,\\
\eta=\frac{r}{R},
\end{cases}$$

so that

$$I_R=\int_0^1\int_0^\pi\frac{R^2\eta^3\cos^2\frac{\varphi}{R
^2}\cos\left(R\eta\sin\frac{\varphi}{R^2}\right)}{R^2\eta^2+1}~\mathrm{d}\varphi~\mathrm{d}\eta.$$

Now as

$$\left\lvert\frac{R^2\eta^3\cos^2\frac{\varphi}{R
^2}\cos\left(R\eta\sin\frac{\varphi}{R^2}\right)}{R^2\eta^2+1}\right\rvert\leq\frac{\eta^3}{\eta^2+\frac{1}{R^2}}\leq\eta$$

for all $R\in(0,\infty)$, and

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{R^2\eta^3\cos^2\frac{\varphi}{R
^2}\cos\left(R\eta\sin\frac{\varphi}{R^2}\right)}{R^2\eta^2+1}=\eta,$$

it follows by the Dominated Convergence Theorem that

$$\lim_{R\to\infty}I_R=\int_0^1\int_0^\pi\eta~\mathrm{d}\varphi~\mathrm{d}\eta=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much~

Answer (score 1):

Let integrand $$f_1(x,y)=\frac{x^2 \cos (y)}{x^2+y^2+1}$$

Transformation into polar coordinates:

$$f_2(r,\theta)=f_1(r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta))=\frac{r^2 \cos ^2(\theta ) \cos (r \sin (\theta ))}{r^2+1}$$

Series expansion of $f_2(r,\theta)$ is ($\theta$ will be very small if $R\to \infty$):

$$f_{approx}(r,\theta) \simeq \frac{r^2}{r^2+1}-\frac{\theta ^2 \left(r^2 \left(r^2+2\right)\right)}{2 \left(r^2+1\right)}+O\left(\theta ^3\right) $$

$$I_R(R) \simeq\int _0^R\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{R^2}} \text{f}_{\text{approx}}(r,\theta )\cdot r \ d\theta dr=\frac{12 \pi  R^6-\pi ^3 \left(R^2+2\right) R^2+2 \left(\pi ^3-6 \pi  R^4\right) \log \left(R^2+1\right)}{24 R^6}$$

Hence the limit for $R \to \infty$:

$$\underset{R\to \infty }{\text{lim}}I_R(R)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much~